# AngularJS resize container

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an issue with my application.
I am trying to build a metro style web app and so far I have used this bit of sass to make my bootstrap horizontal:

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

// ---
// METRO.
// ---

@include screen-md {
    .metro {
        height: 100%;

        .container-fluid {
            width: 10000px;
            padding: 0 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 130px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;

            .row-title {
                position: absolute;
                height: 100px;
            }

            > .row,
            .invisible-container > .row {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                height: 780px;

                padding: 0 15px 30px 15px;
                margin-right: 50px;

                @include make-tiles($tile-width);

                &:last-child {
                    margin-right: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .flex-column {
        display: -webkit-box; /* Safari */
        display: flex;

        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the width of the **.container-fluid** to 10000px. I can't find any CSS way to make this automatically expand.
So I tried to create a directive that would do it for me:

```
.directive('containerFluid', ['$window', '$timeout', '$document', '$http', function ($window, $timeout, $document, $http) {

    var getChildrenWidths = function (children) {

        // Define our width
        var width = 0;

        // If we have any children
        if (children && children.length) {

            // For each child
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

                // Get our child
                var child = children[i];

                // If we are not the back button
                if (!angular.element(child).hasClass('back')) {

                    // Increase our width by the child width
                    width += child.offsetWidth;
                }
            }
        }

        // Return our width
        return width;
    };

    var resize = function (element, width) {

        // Get our document
        var body = angular.element($document[0].body)

        // If our window width is less than 992
        if (width < 992) {

            // Set our container width to 100%
            element.css('width', '100%');

        // Otherwise, if we are large than 992
        } else {

            // Reset our CSS so that widths are calulated properly
            element.css('width', '10000px');
            body.css('overflow-x', 'hidden');

            // Get our last childs length
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[0]),
                paddingRight = parseFloat(style.paddingRight),
                children = element.children(),
                lastChild = children[children.length - 1],
                data = lastChild.getBoundingClientRect(),
                containerWidth = data.right + paddingRight;

            //console.log(paddingRight);
            //console.log(lastChild);
            //console.log(data);
            //console.log(containerWidth);

            // Set our container width
            element.css('width', getChildrenWidths(children) + 'px');
            body.css('overflow-x', 'visible');
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Get our window
            var window = angular.element($window),
            width = $window.innerWidth;

            // Bind to the resize function
            window.bind('resize', function () {

                // After half a second
                $timeout(function () {

                    // Get the window width
                    width = $window.innerWidth;

                    // Resize our container
                    resize(element, width);

                }, 1000);
            });

            // Watch for any children changes
            scope.$watch(function () {

                // If there are any changes to the children
                return $http.pendingRequests.length;

            // Execute if they change
            }, function (length) {

                // If we have no pending requests
                if (length === 0) {

                    // After half a second
                    $timeout(function () {

                        // Resize our container
                        resize(element, width);
                    }, 500);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

There are 2 ways I can execute this bit of code, one of them uses the **getChildWidths** function which calculates the overall width by adding the child widths togeter.
Then there is the **getBoundingRect** method which allows me to get my last child and get it's **right** position and add the container **padding-right** to that value.

If there were no HTTP requests, both methods would work find. The problem is, there are http requests and once those have executed then they are populated within the children of container.
So I have tried to add watch on the http requests length and to execute my directive once there are no requests left, but even that doesn't work properly because it takes time to populate the children.
I would like to refrain from using **timeouts** that exceed 500 milliseconds because then the user is having to wait which is not a good thing.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?